# pygame mastermind, cant print pegs

Tags: python, pygame

I'm doing this as part of my schooling, and have reached a point where whatever I do, I can't seem to tackle it. I am trying to get the clicked colours to display in order into a row of four; however, all I get is a flashing row of four colours which is not what I have coded for.

```
    #MMgame v 2 

import pygame
import random

##pygame set up
pygame.init()
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 800
mm_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mastermind')
pygame.display.update()

##global variables
code = []
user_choice = []

##colours
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
purple = (255,0,255)
green = (94,255,94)
orange = (255,125,38)
blue = (60,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
bg_colour = (255,200,255)
b_colour = (200,191,231)

def user_selection(peg_colour,peg_position):

    if peg_position == 1:
        mm_screen.blit(peg_colour,(40,700))
        pygame.display.update()
    if peg_position == 2:
        mm_screen.blit(peg_colour,(120,700))
        pygame.display.update()
    if peg_position == 3:
        mm_screen.blit(peg_colour,(200,700))
        pygame.display.update()
    if peg_position == 4:
        mm_screen.blit(peg_colour,(280,700))
        pygame.display.update()

def codemaker():

    global code

    for colour in range(4):
        colour_p = random.randrange(1,6)
        if colour_p == 1:
            code.append('purple')
        elif colour_p == 2:
            code.append('green')
        elif colour_p == 3:
            code.append('orange')
        elif colour_p == 4:
            code.append('blue')
        elif colour_p == 5:
            code.append('red')
        elif colour_p == 6:
            code.append('yellow')
    print code

def play():

    print 'playing mm'
    play = True
    while play == True:

        peg_pos = 1 
        global user_choice

        mm_screen.fill(bg_colour)

        purple_p = pygame.image.load('purple_p.png').convert()
        green_p = pygame.image.load('green_p.png').convert()
        orange_p = pygame.image.load('orange_p.png').convert()
        blue_p = pygame.image.load('blue_p.png').convert()
        red_p = pygame.image.load('red_p.png').convert()
        yellow_p = pygame.image.load('yellow_p.png').convert()

        purplepeg = pygame.image.load('purplepeg.png').convert()
        greenpeg = pygame.image.load('greenpeg.png').convert()
        orangepeg = pygame.image.load('orangepeg.png').convert()
        bluepeg = pygame.image.load('bluepeg.png').convert()
        redpeg = pygame.image.load('redpeg.png').convert()
        yellowpeg = pygame.image.load('yellowpeg.png').convert()

        mm_screen.blit(purple_p,(928,614))
        mm_screen.blit(green_p,(1014,614))
        mm_screen.blit(orange_p,(1100,614))
        mm_screen.blit(blue_p,(928,700))
        mm_screen.blit(red_p,(1014,700))
        mm_screen.blit(yellow_p,(1100,700))

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            #finding the position of the cursor
            mp = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #purple selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 928 <= mp[0] <= 1008 and 614 <= mp[1] <= 694:
                if peg_pos == 1:    
                    user_selection(purplepeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('purple')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(purplepeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('purple')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(purplepeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('purple')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(purplepeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('purple')
                    peg_pos += 1
            #green selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 1014 <= mp[0] <= 1094 and 614 <= mp[1] <= 694:
                if peg_pos == 1:    
                    user_selection(greenpeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('green')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(greenpeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('green')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(greenpeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('green')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(greenpeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('green')
                    peg_pos += 1
            #orange selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 1100 <= mp[0] <= 1180 and 614 <= mp[1] <= 694:
                if peg_pos == 1:    
                    user_selection(orangepeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('orange')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(orangepeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('orange')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(orangepeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('orange')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(orangepeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('orange')
                    peg_pos += 1
            #blue selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 928 <= mp[0] <= 1008 and 700 <= mp[1] <= 780:
                if peg_pos == 1:    
                    user_selection(bluepeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('blue')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(bluepeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('blue')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(bluepeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('blue')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(bluepeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('blue')
                    peg_pos += 1
            #red selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 1014 <= mp[0] <= 1094 and 700 <= mp[1] <= 780:
                if peg_pos == 1:

                    user_selection(redpeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('red')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(redpeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('red')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(redpeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('red')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(redpeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('red')
                    peg_pos += 1
            #yellow selected
            if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 1100 <= mp[0] <= 1180 and 700 <= mp[1] <= 780:
                if peg_pos == 1:    
                    user_selection(yellowpeg,1)
                    user_choice.append('yellow')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 2:    
                    user_selection(yellowpeg,2)
                    user_choice.append('yellow')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 3:    
                    user_selection(yellowpeg,3)
                    user_choice.append('yellow')
                    peg_pos += 1
                if peg_pos == 4:    
                    user_selection(yellowpeg,4)
                    user_choice.append('yellow')
                    peg_pos += 1
            print user_choice


codemaker()
play()
```

Comment: because i have no idea what im really doing, im new to coding :<

Answer (score 1):

Your line flashes because you immediately clear the screen after you blitted your code. To fix this do something like:

```
...
mm_screen.fill(bg_colour)
#loop over code list here and blit every color
...
```

---

**EDIT:**

Create a function like:

```
def printCode():
    i = 0
    for color in code:
        if color == "green":
            x = green_p #make a reference to your image
        ...
        mm_screen.blit(x, (40+80*i, 700)) #finally blit the color
        i += 1 #modify the above calculation for the next color
```

And then you call it **AFTER** `mm_screen.fill(bg_colour)`.

---

*But I'll give you some further advices...*

> ```
> while play == True: #yours
> while play: #mine
> ```

It is unnecessary to compare `play` to `True` here as `play` is a bool
and automatically evaluates.

> ```
>  if pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ... #yours
>  if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #mine
> ```

Your selection doesn't work correctly. In this case you **HAVE** to
compare `event.type` because `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is **NOT** a
bool. Its a constant value (even though python doesn't support real constants)!

To save your and the programs time I would suggest you to nest your if-blocks like:

> ```
> ...
> if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>     if 614 <= mp[1] <= 694:
>         if 928 <= mp[0] <= 1008:
>             ...
>         if 1014 <= mp[0] <= 1094:
>             ...
>     ...
>     if 700 <= mp[1] <= 780:
>         if 928 <= mp[0] <= 1008:
>             ...
> ```

Also don't hesitate to do simple calculations. This code can easily be shortened by doing something like:

> ```
> def user_selection(peg_colour,peg_position):
>     mm_screen.blit(peg_colour,(40+80*(peg_position-1),700))
>     pygame.display.update()
>
> #yours: 13 lines | mine: 3 lines
> ```

Don't load images in your main-loop. **You're wasting performance!**

> ```
>   #<----------------- to here -------
>   print 'playing mm'              # |
>   play = True                     # |
>   while play:                     # |
>                                   # |
>       peg_pos = 1                 # |
>       global user_choice          # |
>                                   # |
>       mm_screen.fill(bg_colour)   # |
>                                   # |
>       #move loading from here -------
> ```

There are more things you should change but then this answer would get too long.. ^^ As I said you are doing work your computer could do for you so...

Learn how to [don't repeat yourself!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: thank you for your help :D ill try to improve my code when im awake tomorrow, im not quite sure i understand what you mean by #loop over code list here and blit every color# could you give an example?